# Using an SQL View to dynamically place field data in buckets

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a complex(?) SQL query I am needing to build.  We have an application that captures a simple data set for multiple clients:

```
ClientID | AttributeName | AttributeValue | TimeReceived
----------------------------------------------------------------
002      | att1          | 123.98         | 23:02:00 02-03-20017
----------------------------------------------------------------
003      | att2          | 987.2          | 23:02:00 02-03-20017
```

I need to be able to return a single record per client that looks something like this

```
Attribute | Hour_1 | Hour_2 | Hour_x | 
--------------------------------------
att1                 120.67 | 
--------------------------------------
att2      | 10     | 89.3   |
```

The hours are to be determined by a time provided to the query.  If the time was 11:00 on 02-03-20017, then hour 1 would be from 10-11 on 02-03-20017, and hour 2 from 9-10 on 02-03-20017.  Attributes will be allocated to these hourly buckets based on the hour/date in their time stamp (not all buckets will have data).  There will be a limit on the number of hours allocated in a single query.  In summary, there are possibly 200-300 attributes and hourly blocks of up to 172 hours.  To be honest I am not really sure where to start to build a query like this.  Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: For which database server? MySQL, pgSQL or SQL-server?

Comment: Do you mean that your Attribute table ( Second one ) Will be having the dynamic column headers ( Hour_1, Hour_2 .....Hour_x)?

Comment: The headings don't really matter.  It is really about generating a list of attribute values allocated in sequential hourly buckets.

Comment: We are not really really restricted with regard to database engines although the preference is MySQL or pgSQL

Comment: with postgresql I would start with group by date and hour(TimeReceived), then pivoting with crosstab(...)